# How to check which enumerator is empty in C#?

Tags: c#, list, enumerate

I have two enumerators of `List<MyObject>.Enumerator` and I am using this code:

```
using(List<MyObject>.Enumerator A = someListA.GetEnumerator())
using(List<MyObject>.Enumerator B = someListB.GetEnumerator())
{
    while(A.MoveNext() && B.MoveNext())
    {
        if (!A.Current.Equals(B.Current))
        {
            ...      
        }
    }
}
```

It is possible that one list is empty before the other one in my code. So what would be an elegant way of checking which enumerator is not able to call `.MoveNext()` anymore?

Comment: MoveNext() returns either true or false.  Check the return value and you will know if its reached the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool stateA;
bool stateB;
while ( (stateA = A.MoveNext()) & (stateB = B.MoveNext()))
{
     if (!A.Current.Equals(B.Current))
     {
                    ...      
     }
}
//A' and B' states are available here
```